# CSS3 Viewport parse error

Tags: css, viewport, w3c-validation, parse-error

I have tried changing the bracket to different positions.  The following piece of code from my CSS3 is not accepted by the W3C CSS Validator.   Would someone please help me identify where the parsing error is in the following piece of code?

Many thanks!

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
     @viewport {
         width: 300px;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest a **[`@viewport` at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport)** inside a **[media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**. A media query controls how elements look on the page at certain widths, and `@viewport` is a fallback for [**`<meta name="viewport">`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta). `@viewport` should be outside of the media query, at the base level of your CSS.

Having said that, `@viewport` is **only** relevant when dealing with Internet Explorer's 'snapped mode' on Windows 8 or Windows 10. Considering how little difference it would make, you can pretty much safely ignore it entirely unless you're doing *very* optimised label controls for specific browsers and operating systems.

Setting a META viewport of `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` is enough to handle the various different browsers on mobile devices.

Assuming you are simply trying to adjust an element on the page, you can simply target it directly with the discrepancies when dealing with the various browsers. You can then simply rely on regular media queries to style the page at different widths:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  #id {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I am doing a nanodegree for Full Stack Web Developer and the assignment requires for all browsers and several backwards versions, all screens (RWD). This piece of code would be the first lines of code in my CSS3 it would not be placed in my HTML5 page.  I do have the meta tag you suggested already in my HTML5 source code.

Comment: Then you should be fine; I honestly wouldn't worry about using `@viewport` at all. You'll obviously want to use `@media` queries though. I'd recommend building the site first with just standard media queries (along with the HTML `<meta>` tag), and then seeing how it displays on IE on Windows. If the site displays fine (a 99% chance), you don't need to do anything else :)

Answer (score 1):

Add meta in the head section of your html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And your CSS should be like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 500px) {
  div {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```